# target rest of the document, stop scrolling and toggleClass

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a dropdown menu, and I'm using jQuery to manipulate the DOM. So far, I'm able to toggle the menu into and out of view. Whenever the menu is in view, I have it **CSS** *position* property set to *fixed* with the *top, left and bottom* properties set to *Zero* and its *width* to *90%* as follows

```
.menu-container{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:90%
}
```

My problem is two-fold

1. When I scroll on the menu (for instance, when testing), the rest of
   the document scrolls as well. I would like to confine scrolling to
   the menu container whenever the menu is in view.

   ```
   $('.menu-container').hasClass('menu-open'){
       //rest of body doesn't scroll
   }
   ```
2. Second, since the menu width is set to 90%, I would like to toggle
   the menu out of view whenever one clicks  outside the menu container.

   ```
    $('rest of body').on('click', function(){
       //Toggle menu out of view
   });
   ```

Though I'm looking for a jQuery fix, any other implementation including direct manipulation with raw JavaScript will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Would have to see more, but setting `overflow: scroll` for your menu in the css might fix the first problem.

Comment: You can do this with just css. Set 'overflow-y' to 'auto' or 'scroll' on the menu. For displaying the menu. You might want to use .addClass() and .removeClass() on click to use two different display styles for it.

Comment: I had already implemented that css property before asking; the thing is that I want to disable scrolling on the rest of the document when the menu is on view.

Comment: Add this is part of my code
      $('.menu-button').on('click', function(){
        $('.menu-overlay').addClass('menu-open');
        $('.toggle-cross').removeClass('hidden');
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
      });

Comment: If you want to disable scrolling on the rest of the page the easiest way is to put your menu in a container that is full screen. You can make it transparent if you want, and it will prevent the scroll from hitting the other parts of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document will always scroll during a scroll action unless the mouse is over an element that itself has scroll, i.e. it has `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto` and a fixed height

With this in mind, modify your menu to have

```
overflow: scroll;
height: 300px; /* for example */
```

Next, how to close it on blur. The logic here is you want to invoke closure on any click that is not within the menu - in other words, the click should not be on the menu itself or any of its child/descendent elements. Here's how:

```
$('body').on('click', '*', function() {
    if (!$(this).closest('.menu-container').length) $('.menu-container').hide();
});
```

Since `closest()` checks the matched elements and its parent/ancestors against the passed selectors, it's a good choice for this sort of check.

Comment: Thank you ... your suggestion got me thinking and instead of using the !$(this) selector I put the rest of the content under a wrapper (since the menu was the top most node on the body element) ... From there, everything was a whistle

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

For the first I suggest making your container full screen. Since you said you already had `overflow: scroll` set the other changes would be

```
.menu-container{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And for the second you can do

```
$('body').on('click', function(){
    if(!$(this).closest('.menu-container').length){
        //Toggle menu out of view
    }

});
```

Comment: The 90% was a design consideration. Thanks though

Comment: Sure. By the way, you could just wrap `.menu-container` in a full screen container with `opacity:0`. Same appearance, but prevents background scrolling.

Comment: Cool, I will give that a try and see how things pun out ... Appreciate the hint, really.